# Retain the value of a input text field asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a input text field in my web application which is used as a datepicker.
On the click event of a button the data in the form is validated, if any condition fails, the user is alerted.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
        });
</script>
<input type="text" name="startDate" id="datepicker1" />
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" />
```

The issue here is, the value of the input field is not retained if the data is not valid. I tried to set the value using "datepicker1.Value" but this is not working. Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add runat="server" attribute to input type

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
            //or
            // $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
</script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="startDate" runat="server" id="datepicker1" /><asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: While using runat="server" attribute to my input type it does not allow the datepicker calendar to appear.

Comment: You might have added master page if that is the case then id will be changed while page is given to browser so instead of this use class like below            
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {           
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
</script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="startDate" runat="server" id="datepicker1" /><asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" />

Comment: Thanks. While using class, I am able to retain the value. :)